# Картинка перекрывает текст itextSharp

Tags: c#, файлы, pdf, itextsharp

Работаю в WinForms и iTextSharp. Создаю новый документ PDF ставлю на фон jpg изображение. Пока все хорошо. Но когда пытаюсь добавить еще и текст :
ничего не происходит - текста нет, если же убрать фоновую картинку то текст появляется. При этом если добавлять новую картинку на фоновое изображение то все работает корректно. перекрывается только текст. Вопрос - как исправить ? Код :

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 120, 20, 110, 10);
var FONE = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new FileStream(@"EmptyBlank72dpi.jpg", FileMode.Open));
FONE.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);

using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
{
    document.Open();
    writer.DirectContent.AddImage(FONE);

    for (int i = 0; i < OD.OrdersData().Count; i++)
    {
        document.Add(new Paragraph("_" + OD.OrdersData()[i], font));
        //writer.Add(new Paragraph("_" + OD.OrdersData()[i], font)); так тоже не работает

    }

    document.Close();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Через PdfContentByte выводит текст в нужном месте но в одну строку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не пробовали сделать как советуют [тут](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/image-examples-itext5/background-images)

Comment: @Bald Через PdfContentByte да, работает вывод строки но мне нужно вывести несколько строк через for "\r\n" не переводит каретку в начало строки.

Comment: не совсем понял. а что если строку предварительно *подготовить*: `string.Join("\r\n", src)` и результат вывести в параграф?

Comment: о каком параграфе вы говорите, о таком  pdfcontentbyte.Add(new Paragraph("text", font));
?

Comment: нет, речь о `Document.Add(new Paragraph())`, что мешает Вам вставить строку в которой будет несколько подстрок склеенных через `\r\n`?

Comment: то что они улетят вверх и увидеть их можно только в верхнем крае А1 документа когда у меня А4, поэтому я и ищу способ задать тексту позицию. PdfContentByte задает такую позицию но выводит в одну строку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57236/discussion-between-bald-and-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть возможность перехода на iText7, пожалуйста, сделайте это. iText7 делает макет намного проще и интуитивно понятным. Есть быстрый старт руководство, которое показывает Вам, как работать с iText7 доступна на http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples